# Looping through mysqli row but only no duplicates

Tags: php, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a database which has camera details stored, and I want to loop through the rows of the database and create checkboxes based on the camera model, however if a checkbox already exists with the same camera model i don't want numerous checkboxes being created so as to limit to only one of the same.

I appreciate any help that could guide me towards getting it spot on!

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
    $checkquery = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE session_id = '".$_SESSION["id"]."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$checkquery);
    if (!$result) {
      die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
    echo '<form>';
    echo "<h3>Camera Model: </h3>";
    while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<label>'.$row['model']. '</label>'.'<input type="checkbox" name="categories" value='.$row['model'].' >';
    }
    echo '</form>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this through the SQL query using `DISTINCT`...

```
    $checkquery = "SELECT DISTINCT model 
                    FROM markers 
                    WHERE session_id = '".$_SESSION["id"]."'";
```

But also look into using prepared statements and bind variables to make your application more secure.

**Update:**
There are also a couple of other things...

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<label>'.$row['model']. '</label>'.'<input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="'.$row['model'].'" >';
    }
```

As pointed out by Syscall in the comment, the value attribute should have quotes round it.

AND Please stop using `@` in your code, this hides all sorts of issues which should be fixed rather than hidden.

Comment: Thanks for this! It worked, i'm pretty basic knowledge on all of this so just learning as i go! I'm assuming DISTINCT just means it returns different values, so no duplicates?

Comment: May also indicate missing quotes around the value of the `value` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Syscall, added that and another comment about not using `@`.